# Aggregated result error: Unexpected token 'createddate'

Tags: apex, soql, aggregateresult, createddate

I have the following Aggregated SOQL

```
List<AggregateResult> groupedSpotOnEs = [SELECT my_application__r.numbers__r.Id eSId, status__r.name status, COUNT(Id) recordCount
                                               FROM Spot__c
                                               WHERE  my_application__r.numbers__r.id IN: scope 
                                               AND my_application__r.numbers__r.StartDate__c < createddate 
                                               AND my_application__r.numbers__r.EndDate__c > createddate

                                               GROUP BY my_application__r.numbers__r.Id, status__r.name 
                                               ORDER BY status__r.name ASC];
```

> I get the error Unexpected token 'createddate'.

If I do

```
AND createddate != null
```

or

```
my_application__r.numbers__r.StartDate__c != null
```

There are no errors

I tried creating a formulafield as date with DATEVALUE of created date but that does not work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOQL cannot have a field appear in the right-hand side of a filterexpression

That means that anything like

```
[some field] < [some other field]
```

is not valid syntax

The common workaround is to have a formula field do the comparison, and then add `[formula field] = true` (or `false`) into your query.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `:`

```
my_application__r.numbers__r.StartDate__c < createddate
```

should be

```
my_application__r.numbers__r.StartDate__c < :createddate
```

Assuming you have an apex variable called `createdDate`

Now, if you are trying to compare a record field value against another field value on the same record, you can't do that directly in SOQL, you'll need to define a formula field on the object that returns a boolean true/false

Comment: createddate is a standard field from salesforce

Comment: yes, that is true but as written, it was not obvious if you were comparing against the field or against an apex variable (which is what the compiler thought)